# Can $A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}A$ be simplified?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Let $A$ is an $m\times n$ ($m<n$) real matrix with full positive entries and $\text{Rank}(A)=m$. Thus $(AA^{T})^{-1}$ is an $m\times m$ symmetric $M$-matrix since $AA^{T}$ is nonnegtive and positive definited.

I think $A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}A$ can be simplified to a simple form due to its special structure but I don't know how to do it. I tried using a pseudo inverse and the Cholesky decomposition but they made it more complex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot simplify this, as far as I know. (I'm working with these things daily)

The matrix $P = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ is a projector, that projects onto the image of $A^T$, because it holds
\begin{align*}
P^2  &= P \\
PA^T &= A^T.
\end{align*}

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but I think $P^2=P$ not $I$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's a projector. I got a little too excited there. Edited it.

Comment: Inversely, if I have $P$ such that $P^2 = P$ and $PA^T = A^T$, is $P$ unique (i.e., $P = A^T(AA^T)^{-1} A$)?

Comment: I don't think so, but I can't think of an example right now. If $P^2=P$ and $PA^T=A^T$ then $P$ is a projector onto the space spanned by the columns of $A^T$. But we have not specified "along which axis" we are projecting. (Consider projecting $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\{(x,0)\in\mathbb R^2\}$, you can now choose a direction (except multiples of $[1,0]^T$ along which you can project.) Note this is just intuition, not a proof.